# My Watch OS2 App is not displayed in 'My Watch' application of iPhone when user upgrades app from watch OS1 to watch OS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos

I have a project with watch OS1 architecture configured in it. Now I want to support only watch OS2 architecture in the same project. So in order to configure only watch OS2 in my existing project, I deleted the watch OS1 all targets including Watch App and Watch Extension and I added a new target for watch OS2. With this setup it is working fine if I directly run my application. Both iPhone app and watch app are getting installed.

I am getting issue when I upgrade my iPhone App with watch OS1 settings to the latest settings having watch OS2 target. When I upgrade my app to the latest one by following the below steps then my watch OS2 app is not displayed in **"My Watch"** application on the iPhone. Because of which I'm not able to install my watch OS2 app in my watch.

The steps which I followed are:

1. Install the iPhone app having watch OS1 target. Do not install watch OS1 app on watch device.
2. Tap on 'My watch' app on phone and observe, it displays my watch app name in this section.
3. Now upgrade this App to latest one having Watch OS2 target.
4. Then tap on 'My watch' app on iPhone and observe, there is no my watch app name displayed in this section.

But with the following steps my watch app persists in "My Watch" application.

1. Install the iPhone app having watch OS1 target. Install watch OS1 app on watch device.
2. Tap on 'My watch' app on phone and observe, it displays my watch app name in this section.
3. Now upgrade this App to latest one having Watch OS2 target.
4. Then tap on 'My watch' app on iPhone and observe, my watch app persists in "My Watch" application.

I'm not able to figure out the solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769169/how-to-make-auto-approve-from-iwatch-to-iphone can anyone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are able to install the WatchKit 1 app onto your paired Apple Watch indicates that it is running watchOS 1. From your description it appears that the Watch app on iPhone will not show you WatchKit Apps that are for a version of watchOS that is *newer* than the one you have installed.

You are assuming that in Scenario 2, the Watch app on iPhone is showing you the new WatchKit 2 app installed on the Watch. I suggest, however, that what you are seeing is an indication that the WatchKit 1 app is still installed on the Watch. (This seems like it may be a caching issue, as a WatchKit 1 app would not remain on the Watch for long if it has been removed from the parent application.)

Two further things to add to your testing scenario are:
2) In Scenario 2, delete the WatchKit 1 app from the Apple Watch between Steps 2 and 3, and then observe what happens. I predict you will see something akin to the outcome in Scenario 1. 
1) Upgrade the Apple Watch to watchOS 2, and observe what happens.

A reasonable question is to ask why you are continuing to run an Apple Watch with watchOS 1. Since every Apple Watch ever shipped can run WatchOS 2, and no reason for owners to stay on the earlier version, there is little reason to continue to ship or support a WatchKit 1 extension... even if there were elements of that API that made life a bit easier for us as developers, for certain use cases. WatchKit 1 is dead.

Comment: My App which is already there on the App store has watchKit 1 target.  If suppose user upgrades watch with OS1 to watch OS2, then my app store build(with watchKit 1) will get installed on watch OS2 as well. With this if you consider my mentioned scenarios, then the user is already having watch OS2 in watch but the app which is getting installed on watch has target watchKit 1. So when I update this already installed watchKit 1 app on watch OS2 to the current app which I'm implementing with watch OS2 target then I'm getting the mentioned issues.